# liquibase error String too long more than 4000 charchater

Tags: liquibase

I have question regarding liquibase.I am getting an error while inserting clob type data.String literal is too long.I have mentioned as follows

column name="help_item_text"  type="clob" value="String too long more than 4000 charchaters"

But no luck still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Liquibase uses standard SQL statements so that there is no difference between `updateSql` and `update` modes. For CLOB fields, that can run into problems when the total SQL length gets to be longer than the database's SQL parser can handle.

There is a `valueClobFile` attribute on column that allows you to save the long value to a file and then reference it from the changelog file. This gets the large value out of your changelog file and also tells Liquibase it needs to use a prepared statement.

`<column name="help_item_text" type="clob" valueClobFile="String too long more than 4000 characters">`

Comment: This seems to be good idea but it results in exception as BLOB resource not found "String"

Comment: We should not provide for valueClobFile data.We need to provide file content clob data it works fine